# Activating a script using udev when power supply is connected/disconnected

Tags: linux, udev

I'm trying to get udev to run a couple of small scripts when I connect/disconnect the powersupply. I have the following code in /etc/udev/rules.d/50-caff.rules :

```
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ENV{POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS}=="Charging", RUN+="/home/haukur/rules/off.sh"
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ENV{POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS}=="Discharging", RUN+="/home/haukur/rules/on.sh"
```

Here is on.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
caffeine -a
```

and off.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
caffeine -d
```

Anyway, I wrote these, wrote `udevadm control --reload-rules` into bash and... nothing happened. caffeine doesn't appear to activate at all when I plug or unplug the power supply.

According to `/var/log/syslog` (Ubuntu's replacement for `/var/log/messages`) udev recognizes when I pull the plug:

```
Feb 26 08:44:52 (none) udevd[3838]: starting '/home/haukur/rules/off.sh'
```

but when it tries to run off.sh (which itself tries to run caffeine), it returns this error:

```
udevd[2719]: '/home/haukur/rules/off.sh'(err) '** (caffeine:3840): WARNING **: Command line `dbus-launch --autolaunch=62907743a139af9b3c86412e00000026 --binary-syntax --close-stderr' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.\n'
```

Do you know any way to get around this? Running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with xmonad WM.

Comment: Just a sanity check - do your off.sh and on.sh contain a valid shebang? And I assume you've checked that the attributes you've used are correct for your device?

Comment: Today I learned what a shebang is, and added it to on and off (i.e. added the first line `#!/bin/sh`)- no dice. I have confirmed  that /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0 includes the file `status`, which says `Charging` og `Discharging` depending on which is relevant. This is a Lenovo ThinkPad E520 by the way.

Comment: Don’t forget to chmod +x the shell script and reload the configuration with udevcontrol reload_rules

Comment: Satish: Yeah, I've done that, still nothing, but thanks.

Comment: udevcontrol log_priority=debug  and watch logs on /var/log/messages

Comment: Try: SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ENV{POWER_SUPPLY_ONLINE}=="0"  and SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ENV{POWER_SUPPLY_ONLINE}=="1"

Comment: According to /var/log/syslog (Ubuntu's replacement for /var/log/messages) udev recognizes when I pull the plug `Feb 26 08:44:52 (none) udevd[3838]: starting '/home/haukur/rules/off.sh'`, but when it tries to run off.sh (which itself tries to run caffeine), it returns this error: `udevd[2719]: '/home/haukur/rules/off.sh'(err) '** (caffeine:3840): WARNING **: Command line `dbus-launch --autolaunch=62907743a139af9b3c86412e00000026 --binary-syntax --close-stderr' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.\n'` Do you know any way to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

If the application "caffeine" needs to access you desktop, you probably need to export the DISPLAY before calling the program:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

You may simply prepend this to the command invocation:

```
DISPLAY=:0 caffeine -a
```